# DotNetOpenAuth Service Provider returns too large query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenAuth for Authentication, Once the client request to the DotnetOpenAuth Service Provider for Authentication, It redirect to login page Application, On successful login it return to ReturnPage with large Query String in URL

I got the following issue while running it in the iis server

```
HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
```

I am using the below code for providing the return page url.

> Global.PendingOAuthAuthorization = requestAuth;   string
>   redirect=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OauthRedirect"].ToString();             HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/IdentityProvider/Sites/Authorize.aspx/");

Answer (score 0):

You can change the web config setting for maximum allowable query string length as such:

`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="10240" enable="true" />`

Comment: I have tried it didn't works, I have set the FormAuthentication from different Domain